# writing jquery function in wordpress not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
var images=new Array('img/slider/2.jpg','img/slider/1.jpg','img/slider/3.jpg','img/slider/4.jpg');

var nextimage=0;

jQuery(doSlideshow());

function doSlideshow(){
if(nextimage>=images.length){
   nextimage=0;}
$('element.global-header') 
.css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
.fadeIn(500,function(){setTimeout(doSlideshow,1000);});
}</script>
```

I use it in theme's header in wordpress on console there is no error but it does not do work. Kindly help.

Comment: do you need to echo it out in php? can't you just close the php tag and do it normally? just open the php tag again afterwards - or put it before the php tag

Comment: Probably because you are not wrapping the script in a [DOM ready handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Also, when adding custom scripts to a WP theme, it is recommended that you use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) than manually echoing JS. With what you're doing now you risk wiping out all your JS when you update the theme, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @stender and @Terry, you don't need to use echo and you need to include a document ready function to run the script when the jQuery has finished loading and ready to use. Try this, if it doesn't work then check your theme is including jQuery and there are no errors.

***Edit***

Just a note about the `wp_enqueue_script()` function, you don't need to use this here because you're not including a *script file*, just a small chunk of code. If you did include *a file*, then the enqueue function should go in the themes `functions.php` file. With JavaScript like this, you can simply put it in the `<head></head>` tags within header.php or in the footer **before the closing** `</body>` tag.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var images = new Array('img/slider/2.jpg','img/slider/1.jpg','img/slider/3.jpg','img/slider/4.jpg');

var nextimage = 0;

jQuery(doSlideshow());

function doSlideshow(){

    if(nextimage>=images.length){
        nextimage=0;
    }

    $('element.global-header').css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")').fadeIn(500,function(){ setTimeout(doSlideshow,1000); });

}

});
</script>
```

Comment: Its Still not working and on console it says **jqmigrate migrate is installed version 1.4.1**

Comment: WordPress loads jQuery migrate automatically, that's expected. Try the code above I've changed the namespace from $ to jQuery to match the rest of the code.

Comment: this code shows error until I add library, but after adding it, it does not work and no error in console else **jqmigrate migrate is installed version 1.4.1**